# Can I use any SSD in any laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

Pre-Context: 
I'm good with software but newbie in hardware. I had issues replacing memory for notebook, I found out that there are several models and types of ram memory, and stuffes like voltage, cycles, and others things matter and I didnt know.

Context:
My hard drive is hdd and I want to change to SSD, but I don't know if the SSD I buy will work in another notebook whatever notebook is. If I buy the SSD(which is kind expensive) and my notebook dies suddenly, I want to know if this SSD can be used in (any)other notebook or its like ram memory: full of specifics details.

So can I use any SSD in any laptop?
Thanks

Comment: Can you use any SSD in any laptop, no of course no, but you can install a any compatible SSD in that laptop

Comment: It sounds like you just want to purchase yourself a 2.5" SATA III SSD.  Just keep it mind we don't do hardware recommendations here at Superuser.

Comment: What version of SATA do you have? Maybe the laptop is too old for supporting SATA 3 speeds, so you might lose at least 1/3 speed in that case. Also saw once an old HP laptop with 2.5" HDD, with unconventional connectors, so make sure, if having older laptop, that connectors are standard.

Comment: Who cares about 1/3 speeds when 1/3 speeds are still faster then the mechanical hdd the author has currently.

Comment: It'll still work, assuming you have AHCI capability. I have most of my c2d laptops upgraded with cheap and cheerful SSDs and they work a lot better.

Comment: Thanks, very nice, I'll check it out whether my laptop supports SATA 3.

Comment: There are some rare incompatibilities, but you should be able to use any ssd.

Comment: you can even find SSD with IDE/PATA for ancient computers, although not very easy. So no worry about the SSD, just make sure that you buy the one with the correct connector

Comment: @African Networks: the unconventional connector you're talking about is removable and transferrable to a replacement drive. They're rare since the IDE/PATA days though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Almost*

At this point of time there's roughly 3-4 common SSD form factors. *In most cases* on any laptop that has a conventional hard drive), a 2.5 inch sata hard drive should work. The 7mm Z height is essentially the standard here and should work. This is a safe bet unless your next PC is a really cheap emmc based one (which has soldered on memory) *or* you have a ultrabook (which probably has no sata bay). If it has a hard drive, a sata drive will work.

*However* there's 2 newer form factors which some systems may use. msata is obsoleteish these days and is a smaller, lighter alternative. Its been replaced mostly by m.2 (which has sata and pcie flavours - and not all ports support both). Quite a lot of laptops also have these *alongside* a traditional bay too, and they're more future proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, my notebook has 1 year only, it's a intel i3. 
but well, you said: or you have a ultrabook (which probably has no sata bay). That means ultrabook or comes with ssd or you can't change it? (Yeah, I'm dummie)

Comment: ultrabooks are so slim they either solder in storage, or use a smaller slimmer M2 or msata drive.